# SQL syntax error at or near "order" using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my query.

I'm trying to delete the last N rows.

```
DELETE from Employee order by EmployeeID desc limit 3;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "order"
>  LINE 1: DELETE from
> Employee order by EmployeeID desc limit 3

Comment: Use a subquery to get the last EmployeeID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE
from Employee -- target table
where EmployeeID in (SELECT EmployeeID
                     from Employee
                     order by EmployeeID desc
                     limit 3); -- subquery in condition
```

You should follow [the SQL delete statement syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) and specify the target table in the `from <table>` and then the condition to delete in the `where <statement>`.

Use [subqueries](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-subquery/) to achieve the correct condition.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
DELETE FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeID IN (
    SELECT EmployeeID
    FROM Employee
    ORDER BY EmployeeID
    LIMIT 3
)
```

Comment: _ERROR:  syntax error at or near "limit"
LINE 1: DELETE from Employee limit 3;_